# Using curve_fit for two unknown dependant variables, is this method correct?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am new to python and I am using curve_fit for different calculations in my model and one of my equations include two unknown variables so it is impossible for me to check manually if my code is correct.

my equation is

```
ln(S(b)/S(b50))= -b D + 1/6 b**2 D**2 K
```

My unknowns are D and K

ln(S(b)/S(b50)) is my ydata 
b is my xdata

so I used the following:

```
xdata = np.array([50,300,600,1000])
ydata_beforelog = np.array([426.0938, 259.2896, 166.8042, 80.9248])
ydata = np.log(ydata_before/426.0938)

def func(x, D, K):
    return (-x * D) + (1/6 * (x **2)* (D **2) * K)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
popt[0] = popt[0] * 1000 # I need that for unit scaling

popt = ([ 1.48687053, -0.46540487])
'''

I would assume that those are my D and K?
```

Comment: As I recall, "popt" is short for "Parameters OPTimized", and "pcov" is short for "Parameter COVariance matrix". So yes, popt is the parameters D and K that curve_fit() optimized in this code.

Comment: Thanks, sorry If my question sound basic, I am new to python and my math is basic :)

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest using `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py) - disclaimer: I am a lead author.  That would change your fit to look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

xdata = np.array([50,300,600,1000])
ydata_before = np.array([426.0938, 259.2896, 166.8042, 80.9248])
ydata = np.log(ydata_before/426.0938)

def func(x, D, K):
    return (-x * D) + (1/6 * (x **2)* (D **2) * K)

# create model from this function
mymodel = Model(func)

# create a dictionary of named parameters using the argument names of 
# your model function, so 'D' and 'K'.  Give initial values:
params = mymodel.make_params(D=1.5, K=-1)

# do the fit: fitting ydata with the parameters and
# independent variable "x" as defined by your model function:
result = mymodel.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)

# print the results and fit statistics or just get the best-fit parameters:
print(result.fit_report())

for key, param in result.params.items():
    print(param)
```

That is, you refer to parameters *by name*.   This fill will print out:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(func)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 12
    # data points      = 4
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 0.00709560
    reduced chi-square = 0.00354780
    Akaike info crit   = -21.3382982
    Bayesian info crit = -22.5657095
[[Variables]]
    D:  0.00148687 +/- 1.9408e-04 (13.05%) (init = 1.5)
    K: -0.46540487 +/- 0.71331763 (153.27%) (init = -1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(D, K) =  0.977
<Parameter 'D', value=0.0014868705336113577 +/- 0.000194, bounds=[-inf:inf]>
<Parameter 'K', value=-0.4654048673207782 +/- 0.713, bounds=[-inf:inf]>
```

Comment: Thanks on the reply. It seems that your way provides more data insights. However, I only need the absolute values for D and K which I then collect in Numpy Array and represent as an image.

Comment: @OmarKamal OK, then just extract `result.params['D'].value` and `result.params['K'].value`.   Well... maybe also make an image of the estimated standard deviations (note that `result.params['K'].stderr` is pretty big!).